# Как двигать спрайт в направление куда он смотрит?

Tags: c++, sfml

Есть такой код управления спрайтом:

```
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
    {
        player.move(0, -Speed * time);
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
    {
        player.move(0, Speed * time);                   
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
    {
        player.rotate(-Speed * time);
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
    {
        player.rotate(Speed * time);
    }
```

Спрайт вращается вокруг своей оси, но кпонки w,s перемещают спрайт не так как надо. Как его перемещать в то направление куда он смотрит? Какие формулы применять? Чтоб было наподобие танков с видом сверху.

Comment: Одно слово: векторы.

Comment: Можно подробнее, как в данном случае это можно использовать?

Comment: Конечно не будет. Ты через move меняешь положение только по у. Как вариант, смотреть куда повернут игрок и из этого высчитывать направление.

Comment: Ну вот например: при нажатии клавиши D player.move(10,0), а при нажатии A player.move(-10,0). Ну как я понял, в вашей игре вы хотите сделать именно чтобы игрок двигался под определённом углом, тогда советую вам добавить вектор, и при нажатии D или A изменять в нём x и y, а при нажатии W двигать игрока на этот вектор, а при  S на этот вектор с минусом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вперед - вот так:

```
player.move(Speed * time * cos(угол), Speed * time * sin(угол));
```

Назад - аналогично, только с `-Speed` вместо `Speed`.

Здесь `угол` - это тот угол, который меняется вызовом `player.rotate`.

---

Использовать одну и ту же скорость `Speed` для поворота и движения - слегка странно. Может иметь смысл использовать две отдельные константы.